# Spring Graph Algorithm w Node size

Tags: algorithm, layout, graph, nodes, edges

I need to do some graph layout drawing and have been looking at using something like the Spring layout algorithm as implemented [here](http://snipplr.com/view/1950/graph-javascript-framework-version-001/) and discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028433/graph-auto-layout-algorithm)

However my nodes all have a width and height (is an entity diagram). Can anyone explain how I might incorporate this into the equation?

Answer (score 0):

Taking the [Graph JavaScript Framework](http://snipplr.com/view/1950/graph-javascript-framework-version-001/) as a starting point, you could do the following. I assume that the class `Node` has been extended by attributes `width` and `height`. Then, in the function `layoutRepulsive`, the expression for calculating the distances of nodes has to be changed to respect those sizes:

```
var dx = Math.max(0, Math.abs(node2.layoutPosX - node1.layoutPosX) - 0.5*(node2.width+node1.width));
var dy = Math.max(0, Math.abs(node2.layoutPosY - node1.layoutPosY) - 0.5*(node2.height+node1.height));
```

The maximum function enforces 0 as the lowest possible value for the distance, even when their bounding boxes overlap.

Answer (score 0):

looking inside the first link you procided, there is line 240:

```
var repulsiveForce = this.k * this.k / d;
```

which represent the repulsive potential (that's physics). The larger that number, the less likely is the geometric state. `d` is the distance between two nodes, and `this.k` is the spring stiffness. This potential becomes infinite for distance `d = 0`.

You want to translate this potential by a certain length (the size of your boxes), so replace `d` by `d - length`. That means, the repulsive force becomes infinite at the distance `length`. There still remains the problem, that the repulsive forces then decrease for distances, smaller then `length`, which must be covered by some conditional:

```
if (d + 0.0001 < length) repulsiveForce = bigbigNumber;
```

I added `0.0001` so that the repulsive force never becomes infinite, but only big, because computers don't handle infiniteness very well.