# Auto route lines in a diagram

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

I'm working on a software where a user can make a diagram with boxes and connect these boxes with lines. When A user moves one of the boxes the connector line shall follow and not collide  with any other boxes. I need some sort of path finding. I would like to only allow vertical/horizontal lines. Which path finding algorithm would be preferred to use?

Thanks

Comment: Do some research of your own into *automatic graph layout*, there is a wealth of literature and a fair number of good code libraries covering the topic.

Comment: Following suggestion from @HighPerformanceMark, I found a seemingly similar question at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5028433/98528