# JavaFx and Mind Mapping

Tags: java, tree, javafx

I am building a relatively simple mind-mapping application in JavaFx, without having much knowledge of graph theory.

I've implemented my own Nodes and Curves, and pretty much the only thing I have left to do, is the hardest one, which is automatically positioning the nodes with some algorithm.

I have not really even tried my own solutions yet, but by the looks of it, depending of how elegant I want it to be.. this is not exactly a trivial matter. I'd probably want to have some kind of "circular" layout for the nodes.

I have peeked at JUNG2, which looks very nice, but unfortunately there is no native support for JavaFx. Can I still use it with a JavaFx project?

I'd be very grateful for any resources related to this.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028433/graph-auto-layout-algorithm) can help you :)

Comment: I got lots of information from that, thank you. I also happened to find this: http://blog.jeffreyguenther.com/post/61616273121/exploring-the-possibility-of-graph-layouts-in-javafx