# How to draw a curved arrow in canvas android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have this code to draw the arrow tail line between 2 point but how should I draw curved line for arrow tail?

```
canvas.drawLine(pt1[X], pt1[Y], pt2[X], pt2[Y], paint);//draw line
```

I want to have something like this, whereby the arrow is dynamic

[image]

Comment: Post a screenshot what kind of arrow you want to draw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what shape you want for the curved line, you could perhaps use [`Canvas.drawArc()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint)), but that is restricted to sections of an oval aligned with the screen axes.

For a more general approach, define your curved line as a [`Path`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) and then use [`Canvas.drawPath()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPath(android.graphics.Path,%20android.graphics.Paint)) to render it to the canvas. A `Path` can be composed of an arbitrary number of straight line, quadratic curve, and cubic curve segments. (See the docs for how to construct the `Path` that you want.) For a solid arrow tail, you should set the paint's style to `FILL` when calling `drawPath()`.

Comment: Do you have any example on how to draw it?

Comment: @ZhengXian - Drawing it isn't the problem--just build a `Path` and call `canvas.drawPath(path, paint);`. The problem is how to compute a path. Given your sample image, that's a difficult layout problem that's far different from the question you originally asked. Take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028433/graph-auto-layout-algorithm) and also search the web for _graph layout algorithms_.

Comment: But is there any open source graph layout algorithms for Java API rather than javascript

Comment: @ZhengXian - In the thread I referenced, one of the answers suggests using JGraph (a [GitHub project](https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx)) for Java. I have no experience with this or whether there are other packages available.